# str_split into multiple rows and copy strings from another column based on delimiter in r

Tags: r, string, dplyr, split, tidyverse

I would also accept a pandas solution, my company does not like to use r.

I have been given a nightmare of a dataset and need some help transforming it in r using tidyr

example df record:

```
id  date              people                                     things
12  12/12/12    last, first [id124] last, first middle [id1782] thing 1\nthing 2\nthing 3\n    thing 4\nthing 5
```

I need to split the people at their ID, and then split the things and match them to the people.  the things are separated amongst the people in order by "\n    ".

the desired end result:

```
id  date          people                    things
12  12/12/12    last, first [id124]         thing 1
12  12/12/12    last, first [id124]         thing 2
12  12/12/12    last, first [id124]         thing 3
12  12/12/12    last, first middle [id1782] thing 4
12  12/12/12    last, first middle [id1782] thing 5
```

I cannot make an attempt good enough to even share here.

Comment: please show the dput of example

Comment: i have the desired result.  not sure how to post a dput for something i can't even begin to achieve.

Comment: What determines that thing1 to 3 is for id 124

Comment: the lack of a carriage return after the line break.  "\n    " denotes the separation of things in relation to people.

Comment: can you check the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use double `cSplit` - i.e. first split at the `]` followed by spaces or (`|`) newline (`\n`) with more than 1 space (`\\s{2,}`).  In the 'long' format returned, do the second split on 'things' column at newline and if needed restore the `]` that was removed in the split in 'people' (regex lookaround doesn't seem to be working for `cSplit`)

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
cSplit(df1, c("people", "things"), sep='\\] |\n\\s{2,}', 'long', 
     fixed = FALSE) %>% 
    cSplit("things", sep="\n", "long") %>%
    mutate(people = str_replace(people, "(\\d+)$", "\\1]"))
```

-output

```
#    id     date                      people  things
#1: 12 12/12/12         last, first [id124] thing 1
#2: 12 12/12/12         last, first [id124] thing 2
#3: 12 12/12/12         last, first [id124] thing 3
#4: 12 12/12/12 last, first middle [id1782] thing 4
#5: 12 12/12/12 last, first middle [id1782] thing 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 12L, date = "12/12/12", people = "last, first [id124] last, first middle [id1782]", 
    things = "thing 1\nthing 2\nthing 3\n    thing 4\nthing 5"),
    row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: when i enter this into my script and replace it with the actual table information it seems to duplicate and be misaligned.  can we chat?

Comment: @zabada that is the reason I requested to show the dput of the example.  if you check my post, I showed a reproducible example with `data` from `dput` which gives the correct structure